# React Native Error create new project ' Copying template '

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

when I'm try create new react native project
on macos Ventura 13.2

```
✔ Downloading template
✖ Copying template
error Error: Couldn't find the "/var/folders/mn/m8xhgjss2cj0jf5svmxg_2vm0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-VUPUIq/node_modules/react-native/template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template.
Error: Error: Couldn't find the "/var/folders/mn/m8xhgjss2cj0jf5svmxg_2vm0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-VUPUIq/node_modules/react-native/template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template
    at createFromTemplate (/Users/imac/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:129:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/imac/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:181:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/imac/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling the following

`sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli`

Nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by updating the system to 13.2.1
Then execute

```
sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli

npx react-native init AwesomeProject --npm
```

Comment: Weird that it doesn't work without the --npm flag

Comment: Yes, this is strange, and today the same problem happened

Comment: Adding `--npm` worked for me as well. WTH? Why do we need this?